# Migration from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.4.5 results in strange server error 500

Tags: migration, joomla2.5, server-error, joomla3.4

I installed a brand new, clean Joomla 3.4.5 and then installed a component written by myself, which worked totally fine in Joomla 2.5. In Joomla 3 however, I get server error 500... in some cases...

I narrowed the error down to the following weird situation:

The component is called com_confighdv (I'm extending Joomla core's com_config). I added a view called JustaName, existing of two files:

admin/views/justaname/view.html.php:

```
<?php
class ConfigHdVViewJustaName extends JViewLegacy
{
}
?>
```

admin/views/justaname/tmpl/default.php:

```
Hello world!
```

This works fine when I go to index.php?option=com_confighdv&view=justaname.

Then I change the view's name from JustaName to Component:

- The view's folder becomes: admin/views/component/
- Class declaration becomes: `class ConfigHdVViewComponent extends JViewLegacy {}`

Now, when I go to index.php?option=com_confighdv&view=component I get a server error 500 :s

I really don't know what to do with this. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Look in the server logs for the exact error message, that's likely to be the most enlightening thing you can do

Comment: Lines in server log (= normal log, error logs are empty): ------- [19/Nov/2015:11:55:24 +0100] "GET /administrator/index.php?option=com_confighdv&view=justaname HTTP/1.1" 200 5693 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36" ---------- and: -------- [19/Nov/2015:11:56:28 +0100] "GET /administrator/index.php?option=com_confighdv&view=component HTTP/1.1" 500 174 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"

Comment: I suspect component is already assigned for a view type. Try changing it to comp? Alternatively enable Joomla! Maximum error reporting to view the php error.

Comment: @XWS Thanks for the hint of enabling Joomla's maximum error reporting! Solved the problem immediately (see my own answer below). Really thought I was already using maximum error reporting, because that is what I want when I am creating extensions...

Comment: You actually want development when developing ;-). You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Switching to Joomla's maximum error reporting provided the explanation:

> Fatal error: Class ConfigHdVModelComponent contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (JModelForm::getForm) in /xxx/administrator/components/com_confighdv/models/component.php on line 18

So, the problem is not in the view, but in the model that belongs to the Component view!

I accidentally created this problem myself, by reducing the model declaration to what I thought was the absolute minimum:

```
class ConfigHdVModelComponent extends JModelAdmin
{
{
```

While this is not allowed, because you always have to define the `getForm` method, so:

```
class ConfigHdVModelComponent extends JModelAdmin
{
    public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
    {
    }
{
```